# How to create a function to specific Attractor element as a destination of moveTo block in Anylogic

Tags: java, arrays, anylogic

I'm trying to create a function that returns the specific attractor destination to the moveTo block.
The function will check if the 1st attractor is busy will go to check the next attractor. If the next attractor is available then product moveTo that attractor destination.
Struggling at how to reach attractor as an element of an array and return that element to be a destination of moveTo. Also how to loop checking the condition of next attractor if that attractor is not available.

I tried to use the collection and population agent. But cannot return the attractor element.

Please advise, and thank you for your comment.[Attractor model photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbRbX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use a LinkedHashMap for instance called yourCollection in which the key will be of type Attractor and the value will be a boolean (true if it's free, false if it's busy)... then you can just do yourCollection.get(yourAttractor) and it will return a true or false

Initialize it like this:

```
for(Attractor a : collectionCellTest){
    yourCollection.put(a,false);
}
```

and your function to return a free attractor should be something like this:

```
for(Attractor a : yourCollection.keySet()){
    if(yourCollection.get(a)){
         return a;
    }
}
return null;
```

You can also put resources in the attractors and just use moveTo the seized resource unit... this would be the most robust way I think.

If you want to do more special stuff with the attractor, you can also consider using a collection of classes in which the class will have the attractor and if it's free or not at least.